# docker-compose postgresql docker-entrypoint-initdb.sh not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml is

```
  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM postgres:10.5-alpine
COPY /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The scripts from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder are exists inside the container, but not running

If i run this scripts inside the container they work fine.

I also tried to remove the container and rebuild it again and again but it is still not working!

Comment: You need to run a command or script. `COPY` do not execute any script by himself

Comment: The documentation of postgres docker says that I need just copy all my sql and sh scripts into the folder

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was just an error with my sh script. I had found the error with

> docker logs k4fntr_database

command

Answer (score 0):

"Warning: scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

**One common problem** is that if one of your /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and your orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized data directory, it will not continue on with your scripts."

From https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

**Update1**:

Are you sure the host folder is `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` ? (on root path from you host, look weird). Maybe somethign like `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Comment: Yes. But my scripts don't even run.

Comment: make sure scripts you want to run got right to execute `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: Yes. I do RUN chmod 0755 -R /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ but there is no effects

Comment: @J-Jacques M - I had this problem. ie my scripts did not have execute permissions. Thanks for the pointer.